# XSLT: copy part of external XML and change specified elements

Tags: xml, xslt, copy, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

The question seems kinf of basic but I still can't figure out how to do this simple task with only one stylesheet:

Copy a part from an external XML and change one specific element within that part in the output:

```
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!--This part loops, i.e. does not work: copy-of works but then I cannot change anything of course -->
    <xsl:template match="t:teiHeader">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="document('example.xml')//t:teiHeader"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="t:publicationStmt/t:ref[@target='bla1']">
        <ref target="bla2"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

The only idea I had was using two stylesheets. First copy-of and then change the desired elements. But I figured it can't be that difficult. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use two modes, so that you can have two ways of processing `t:teiHeader` elements e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="t:teiHeader">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="document('example.xml')//t:teiHeader" mode="copy"/>
</xsl:template>
```

plus

```
<xsl:template match="t:teiHeader" mode="copy">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#default"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

or plus

```
<xsl:mode name="copy" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/> 

<xsl:template mode="copy" match="t:publicationStmt/t:ref[@target='bla1']"><ref target="bla2"/></xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works (no modes needed), although I am not sure why (maybe someone can explain):

```
<xsl:template match="t:teiHeader">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="document('example.xml')//t:teiHeader/(@*|node())"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: You have not really shown the complete output you want but if you only process the attributes and child nodes of the `t:teiHeader` element with `apply-templates` the resulting document will not contain the `t:teiHeader` element itself, only its attributes and descendants.